# Move window between editors

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I hit `Ctrl-\`, I can split my editor into two editors, `Left` and `Right`.

What I would like to do is move a `Window` from the `Left` editor into the `Right` editor using a keyboard shortcut.

I don't see any command for that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_editorwindow-management

Am I missing it, or is that functionality not presently available?

Comment: Move window or tab?

Comment: @Alex I am using the terms interchangeably, perhaps I shouldn't. If I click `File -> New Window`, I get a new window under a tab labelled `Untitled-1`. I want to move `Untitled-1` to the `Right` editor - how would I do that?

Comment: Thanks @Alex - that appears to be the feature I want, but for whatever reason I can't perform it.